# Unexpected behavior when casting from list to string on Python

Tags: python, string, printing, casting

I was messing around with Python when I found this behavior I can't really make sense of it. Code is the following:

```
x = ['A','B','C','D']
x = str(x)
y = "ABCD"

print(f"x = {x} \nx.find('B') is: {x.find('B')}\n\n")
print(f"y = {x} \ny.find('B') is: {y.find('B')}\n\n")

print(x)
print(y)

print(type(x)==type(y))
```

and the output on the console is:

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
x.find('B') is: 7


y = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y.find('B') is: 1


['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
ABCD
True
```

Things I don't fully understand are:
Why x and y are showed as lists when printed in a formatted string?

Why when using simply `print(x)` or `print(y)` the ways of printing are different, even though `type(x) == type(y)`?

And specially why `x.find('B')` is 7, when the length of the string/list is 4, while `y.find('B')` works as expected?

Probably a trivial question but I didn't find something similar on the site. Thanks!

Comment: The fornatted string of `y` looks like `str(x)` and inconsistent with `str(y)` because you are using `x` instead of `y` on line 6

Comment: @ronpi oh... that was dumb, wasn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `print(y)` output looks weird is because you're actually passing `x` to `print`. As well, what you're seeing with `x.find('B')` is happening because you're converting 'x' to a `str`. This doesn't give you a list, but instead a string that looks like `"['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']"`. So here `B` really is the 7th index of the string

Comment: Oh I see. It's weird how that works. I didn't think it would convert the syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Shay what's weird, exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To me it feels weird that str([1,2]) = "[1, 2]" (Notice the space after the comma). The syntax you use to to declare a list is also converted. In my mind the brackets and commas are what you use to make the list, not something the machine should see. It'd feel more natural if str([1,2]) = "12", similar to list("12") = ['1', '2']. But what do I know

Comment: @Shay it's *totally arbitrary*, it's just a convenient representation to print. `12` would be *totally ambiguous*. No, that wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you elaborate? To me it'd feel more natural if `s= str(list)` would be equivalent to `s = ""; for element in list: s = s + str(element)`

Comment: @Shay because the `str` constructor accepts *arbitrary objects*. Basically, all objects inherit a string representation from `object`. Your implementation makes sense *if it accepted only iterables*. But it doesn't. In contrast, the `list` constructor accepts iterables only.